# UDP receive only once

Tags: c#, udp

I made a simple server with UDP listening on 6789 port.

The client send a message and the server receive the message but only the first message.

Then, the port its open as I see, but the receive is not fires again.

Here is the code on FormLoad()

```
      Thread thdUDPServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverThread)); thdUDPServer.Start();
```

And the serverThread()

```
public void serverThread()
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(6789);

        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

        string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes); 
        if (returnData.Contains("something"))
        {
            
            //do something;
           
        }
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Is there some while loop that isn't included in your code example? Because if not then your thread code just terminates once it reaches the end of the method `serverThread()`

Answer (score -2):

Oh that was very quick.
I finally find it.
Maybe are many better approaches but i solved closing the udpClient with

```
udpClient.close();
```

and start listening again

```
Thread thdUDPServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverThread)); thdUDPServer.Start();
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very good approach, and I don't think it's going to be reliable.  Have a look at [this code](https://www.codeguru.com/visual-basic/communication-using-udp-and-visual-basic/) as an example of how it should probably be done.

Comment: Why you think is not reliable ?

Comment: @RubyKousinovali: Instead of creating a new socket again and again and do a single read on each socket, one should create the socket once and do multiple reads. Apart from a waste of performance your approach also has reliability problems: Packets will only be delivered to an existing socket, so if the sockets gets closed and recreated there will be a time when the socket does not exist. Any packets sent in this time will simply be discarded. Also, packets sent before the socket got closed will be discarded too once the socket gets closed.